# List iteration - Generic logic

Tags: java, generics

I have a list of beans (`List<AClass>`), from which I am creating two sub list based some logic which involves checking a field from the bean class, say action. if

```
bean.getAction.equals("true") - add to new sublist - List<AClass> listA
else - add to new sublist - List<AClass> listB
```

I have created a method for it and it works fine.

Now I have similar task for other Bean class as well where i have `List<BClass>` which also has action field and getAction method. I want to create a generic method which would cater to both these beans (and other similar beans as well).

How can I create such method?

Comment: do you really need such method? maybe it would be better to define Predicate and use [commons collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) filter()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `List<? extends ParentClass>` where `ParentClass` is parent of `AClass` and `BClass`

Answer (score 3):

If `AClass` and `BClass` share a common base then a wilcard type can be used - `List<? extends CommonBase>`

Comment: Just 3 seconds after yourself :)

Comment: But then each parameter can be of a different class

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
interface HasAction {
    public String getAction();
}

public class AClass implements HasAction {
    private final String action;

    public AClass (String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

}
public class BClass implements HasAction {
    private final String action;

    public BClass (String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

}

public <T extends HasAction> List<T> subList(List<T> list) {
    List<T> subList = new ArrayList<T> ();

    for ( T source : list ) {
        if ( source.getAction().equals("true")) {
            subList.add(source);
        }
    }
    return subList;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have written now, Thanks for taking extra effort of writing the code!